# AJAX response 200, but no JSON response data from PHP script running on XAMPP localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

The `HTML` code calls a **localhost** `function` `getNodes` which responds with JSON lint verified JSON; however, when the same function is called using AJAX from a javascript file, a 200 response code is received, but no response data.  I’ve spent 2.5 days searching, researching and experimenting with various AJAX content and data type and php file header, options.  I’ve experimented with relative versus absolute urls.  I’ve confirmed that the following **Mime types** are valid in **XAMPP MIME** file

- Application/json Application/javascript Javascript

Still, `200 response`, but no response data when calling via **AJAX**.  I've included the javascript and HTML below.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var getNodesUrl = "../getNodes.php";
  
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: getNodesUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { classification: "skills" },
    success: function(nodes){
      console.log("successful ajax call");
      console.log(nodes);
      var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000, 400,1);
      sys.parameters({gravity:true});
      sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport");
      sys.graft(nodes);    
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log("ajax call failed");
    }
  })
 
  
});
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/lab/public/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/lab/public/scripts/arbor.js" ></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/lab/public/scripts/graphics.js" ></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/lab/public/scripts/renderer.js" ></script>
        
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php 
            require("../getNodes.php");
            $_POST['classification'] = "skills";
            getNodes();
        ?>
                  <canvas id="viewport" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
                  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/index.js" ></script>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the **PHP** script that generates the valid **JSON**.

```
<?php

function getNodes()
{
require_once("../../includes/config.php");
header('Content-Type: json');

$classification = $_POST['classification'];
$nodes = array();
$edges  = array();
$i = 0;

$classes = query("SELECT * FROM classifications WHERE label = ?", $classification);
if (sizeof($classes) != 0)
{   
    $nodes = '{"nodes":{"' . $classification . '":{"color":"blue","shape":"dot","label":"' . $classification . '"}';
    $edges = '"edges":{"' . $classification .'":{ ';
    $classes = query("SELECT * FROM classifications WHERE label = ?", $classification);
    foreach ($classes as $clas)
    {
        $nodes = $nodes . ',"' . $clas['child'] . '":{"color":"' . $clas['color'] . '","shape":"dot","label":"' . $clas['child'] . '"}';
        $edges = $edges . '"' . $clas['child'] . '":{}';
        if ($i < (sizeof($classes)-1))
        {
            $edges = $edges . ",";
        }

    $i+=1;
    }

    $nodes = $nodes . "},";
    $edges = $edges . "}}}";
    $data = $nodes . $edges;
    echo $data;
}
else
{
    echo "{}";
}
}
?>
```

JSON Output

```js
{
    "nodes": {
        "skills": {
            "color": "blue",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "skills"
        },
        "Biology and life sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Biology and life sciences"
        },
        "Computer and information sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Computer and information sciences"
        },
        "Earth sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Earth sciences"
        },
        "Ecology and environmental sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Ecology and environmental sciences"
        },
        "Engineering and technology": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Engineering and technology"
        },
        "Medicine and health sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Medicine and health sciences"
        },
        "People and places": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "People and places"
        },
        "Physical sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Physical sciences"
        },
        "Research and analysis methods": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Research and analysis methods"
        },
        "Science policy": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Science policy"
        },
        "Social sciences": {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "Social sciences"
        }
    },
    "edges": {
        "skills": {
            "Biology and life sciences": {},
            "Computer and information sciences": {},
            "Earth sciences": {},
            "Ecology and environmental sciences": {},
            "Engineering and technology": {},
            "Medicine and health sciences": {},
            "People and places": {},
            "Physical sciences": {},
            "Research and analysis methods": {},
            "Science policy": {},
            "Social sciences": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: HTML code is your `getNodes.php`, if yes where are you echoing the json output? If no, please paste the contents of `getNodes.php` too.

Comment: What does your console say, Any errors?

Comment: Php Functions will not run without call.. It has to be called

Comment: @jigar, the HTML code is pasted above as is getNodes.php.  The echo statement is on about line 33 above.

Comment: @Kepoly I print to console.log a message following the json call and so, ironically enough, i get the statement "successful ajax call".  The next statement attempts to send the response data to the console.  A blank line is sent to the console.

Comment: @dellaboemia also please paste the valid json, as its generated, there are high chances that it has errors. paste your json code here http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and don't forget to check the checkbox for validation.

Comment: and you are making things more complicated unnecessary, create an array first and then `echo json_encode`, that is it.

Comment: @jigar, i pasted the json above.  It's valid according to JSON Lint.  Also, the app for which the data is being prepared requires a specific JSON format to render certain visualizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

function getNodes()
{
require_once("../../includes/config.php");
header('Content-Type: json');

$classification = $_POST['classification'];
$nodes = array();
$edges  = array();
$i = 0;

$classes = query("SELECT * FROM classifications WHERE label = ?", $classification);
if (sizeof($classes) != 0)
{   
    $nodes = '{"nodes":{"' . $classification . '":{"color":"blue","shape":"dot","label":"' . $classification . '"}';
    $edges = '"edges":{"' . $classification .'":{ ';
    $classes = query("SELECT * FROM classifications WHERE label = ?", $classification);
    foreach ($classes as $clas)
    {
        $nodes = $nodes . ',"' . $clas['child'] . '":{"color":"' . $clas['color'] . '","shape":"dot","label":"' . $clas['child'] . '"}';
        $edges = $edges . '"' . $clas['child'] . '":{}';
        if ($i < (sizeof($classes)-1))
        {
            $edges = $edges . ",";
        }

    $i+=1;
    }

    $nodes = $nodes . "},";
    $edges = $edges . "}}}";
    $data = $nodes . $edges;
    $content = $data;
}
else
{
    $content = "{}";
}
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo $content;
}
?>
```

Notice the `header("Content-Type: application/json");` in PHP file.

Comment: Thanks @Jigar, i'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `contentType`, your content type should be

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

Also your  `datatype: "json",` should be

```
 dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Thanks Solanki.  The contentType of "application/json" and datatype"json" were tried, with no result. The option values listed above were only the last of about 2^4 different combinations.  I wished it were that easy:-)